# Why my ng-click not working

Tags: javascript

I am not sure why ng-click is not picking up the function. I tried assigning my 'Next' function to a scope variable and it still didn't work.

Here is the HTML (exluding the 'App' bit in the  element)

```
<div ng-controller="CarouselCtrl">
    <div>
        <img src="" class="carousel-arrow" ng-click="Next();">
        <h1>{{Index}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('CarouselCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    var Carousel = {};

    Carousel.Data = ['Slide 1', 'Slide 2', 'Slide 3', 'Slide 4', 'Slide 5']
    Carousel.Index = 0;

    Carousel.Next = function() {

        if (Carousel.Index >= Carousel.Data.length) {
            Carousel.Index = 0;

        } else {
            Carousel.Index++
        }
    }

        $scope.Index = Carousel.Data[Carousel.Index];
        $scope.Next = function(){
        Carousel.Next();
        console.log('clicked');
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Is your top div wrapped in a tag with an `ng-app` attribute?

Comment: yes it is.:) I Well it is now detecting the clicks but not updating the {{index}} variable when clicked.

Comment: That's because you're not updating the $scope.Index variable; update it in your else branch with `$scope.Index = Carousel.Data[Carousel.Index];`

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.Next = Carousel.Next();
```

change to

```
$scope.Next = Carousel.Next;
```

By doing `$scope.Next = Carousel.Next();` the scope `Next` is no longer a function but just value returned by the `Carousel.Next()` function. So all you have to do is assign function definition just like above.

**Update**

```
$scope.Next = function(){
        Carousel.Next();
        $scope.Index = Carousel.Data[Carousel.Index];
        console.log('clicked');
}
```